# Incorrect page title - Magento 2.1.

Tags: magento-2.1, php, url

For some reason when I access Login page I get on browser title "Payments".
I searched everywhere for word "Payments" in my code and in Magento admin and remove it completely. The word "Payments" has gone from everywhere except from Login page title.

What I would like to do now is go into login.phtml or anywhere else and say:

```
if ($url = 'login') { setTitle('login')}
```

But, I have failed. No matter what I do "Payments" stays. I belive if I deleted the all Internet the word "Payments" will still remain.

Can someone help me force the title change on that login page?

Comment: Is it default setup? Or after customization?

Comment: After the customization.

Comment: can you clear cache and try